# Parsing Large XML with lots of tags

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to transform a large xml file containing lots of tags to Java Classes for parsing.but since there are large no of tags its difficult to create Java class for each task.is there anything that can automate this.

There are around 200 unique tags and its a 400mb xml file.

What am trying to do is parse a xml and generate csv's for it which will be later inserted into a table.

Comment: Could you please paste the approach in which you are trying to resolve..

Comment: Is there any DTD or XSD for the xml?

Comment: You can read the class and generate the class code or you can use a `Map<String, Object>`

Comment: not quite sure what you want, but ... check JAXB

Comment: your question is not very clear so its a little difficult to help. did you mean "create a java class for each tag"?

Comment: @ShashiBhushan:there is xsd for the xml

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: but for JAXB we would require to create Java Classes for each Tags??I am not complete sure but this is what i understood by looking up JAXB.

Comment: You can use xmlbeans.  http://xmlbeans.apache.org/

Comment: @Joe Dominic Valluvassery: it can automatically create them, if you have the schema (XSD).

Comment: @ShashiBhushan:will explore ! thankS!

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite vague, I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you might be interested in learning about SAX.

There are 2 main ways of parsing XML in Java, DOM and SAX. SAX is better for large documents as DOM loads the whole document into memory, whereas SAX is sequential and event-driven

Easy tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)